# Electron Take Up 100% Of Screen (Not Full Screen)

Tags: electron

I've got an electron app, below is the `main.js` file:

```
var app = require('electron').app;
var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 715,
        width: 1200,
        minWidth: 600,
        minHeight: 200,
        center: true
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

As you can see, the width and height are specified. What I want is for the app to open, but take up all of the available screen (but *NOT* to be in full screen, such that the dock and tool bar of the OS are hidden).

In simple CSS this is done by using

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

I want to be able to reproduce this in my electron app, although cannot seem to find any details on how to do it

Note: `fullscreen: true` is not what I am looking for, as that makes the app open so that the dock and toolbar are hidden

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Call `mainWindow.maximize()` to maximize the window after you create it.

Comment: Just another tip: you should not set resizable to true while you use this

Answer (score 189):

use this!

```
win = new BrowserWindow({show: false});
win.maximize();
win.show();
```

Comment: best answer - just show the window when it's already resized :)

Comment: Btw that last `win.show()` call isn't strictly necessary after the `win.maximise()` because `win.maximise()` will show the window anyway.

Answer (score 36):

Use this:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron

let win

app.on('ready', () => {
   const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
   win = new BrowserWindow({width, height})
   win.loadURL('https://github.com')
})
```

Comment: This increases the window size but does not entirely fit the working area.

Comment: This might the best answer,, I was getting windows.innerWitdh in render process, this might be useful

Answer (score 12):

try this code after your mainWindow declaration

```
mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.maximize()
})
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, only add `titleBarStyle: 'hidden'` to declaration of your window.

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    movable: false,
    resizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    minimizable: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden', // watch this line
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      DevTools: false,
    }
  });
```

note that I only have tested on Windows OS and it can be change in other OS like Mac.